# set value for a dropdown

Tags: php, html

I have a db table that can be described like this

```
CREATE TABLE TTT (id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name VARCHAR(64), quantity INT, available VARCHAR(5));
```

I have a link to display a particular product information on the screen which I also set up a drop down box to display "available" content (that is whether it is still "in stock" IN_ST or "out of stock" OF_ST). How can I read one of the value and display it in the combobox as a default value after clicking the link. Thank you so much for your help.

My select html looks something like this

```
<select name="available" id="available">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="IN_ST">In stock</option>
    <option value="OF_ST">Out of stock</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to check in your loop to see if the current value is the one to make default, and `echo "selected";` in the option if so.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to post what you have already?

The simplest way is to construct a drop-down with each value mapping to the value of the `id` column in your database.  This would allow you to select and display the details.

The query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TTT
```

The drop-down menu itself would be something like:

```
<SELECT id="stock">
<OPTION value="1">ABC (out of stock)</OPTION>
<OPTION value="2">DEF (out of stock)</OPTION>
<OPTION value="3">GHI (in stock)</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

The idea being, the value column would be populated using the `id` column like I mentioned earlier.  You can display the name and along with that use a simple `if ... else` to display if the item is in stock or not.

```
$status = $row['available'] == 'IN_ST' ? ' (in stock)' : ' (out of stock)';
$option = "<OPTION value={$row['id']}>{$row['name']}$status</OPTION>";
echo $option; // within the select
```

Hope that gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    // $someId might come from the query string, or some other place
    $query = "SELECT * FROM TTT WHERE id = $someId";

    if (!$result = mysql_query($query))
    {
      die(); //properly handle the error
    }
    //since I'm where'ing the id, I'm assuming only one row will be returned.
    //If that's not the case, you'll have to put this in a while construct
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

    $avail = $row['available'];
    $in_selected = ($avail == "IN_ST") ? "selected" : "";
    $out_selected = ($avail == "OUT_ST") ? "selected" : "";

?>
<select name="available" id="available">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <option value="IN_ST" <? echo $in_selected; ?>>In stock</option>
    <option value="OF_ST" <? echo $out_selected; ?>>Out of stock</option>
</select>
```